# How did a community ad show up in a stackexchange where it was not promoted?

Tags: discussion, area-51, advertising, site-promotion, community-promotion-ads

I recently saw the [Korean Language and Usage Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language?referrer=_bGLWL4a0nyN5qIsOP5VxA2) community ad show up at the new Law stackexchange

However the Korean Language proposal was not added as a community ad in the [related meta post](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/community-promotion-ads)

Moreover, it was added to be [promoted on travel SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/6464) but I have never seen it come up there

How do these community ads work, and how can this system be used to better promote an Area51 proposal?

Comment: It's not part of the Community Promotion Ads, it's a network wide effort to push Area 51 proposals a bit.

Comment: In case of travel SE where it was recommended as an ad, I have never seen it appear. Is it just coincidence that it never appeared while I was looking, or do the higher upvoted ads get more preference? The Korean Language Community Ad does have the minimum required 6 upvotes

Comment: It's not showing often, but according to [this](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1969), it was **clicked** 103 times. Just keep reloading and you'll eventually see it. :)

Comment: Update: looks like it's not random on every page load anymore, but static for a while. I refreshed 10 times, and the same ad shows up. But still, they should all rotate at some point, and if not - time for bug report. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, may be someone can look into it